# "==" always returning true. Anagram program

Tags: c#, anagram

I have made a simple function which checks if two words are an anagram by sorting and comparing the sorted values, however this program always returns true even if the words aren't anangrams. If I remove the .ToString() it evalutates as false. Any idea why it's doing this and any ideas on how to fix this?

```
public bool anagram(string word1, string word2)
    {
        char[] word1Arr = word1.ToArray();
        char[] word2Arr = word2.ToArray();

        Array.Sort(word1Arr);

        Array.Sort(word2Arr);

        Console.WriteLine(word1Arr);
        Console.WriteLine(word2Arr);

        if (word1Arr.ToString() == word2Arr.ToString())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Have you checked what the output of `word1Arr.ToString()` is?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular of sample of your data would be helpful.

Comment: word1Arr.ToString() will print something like "char[]". So it's always true because both valeus are char[]. Try using SequenceEqual (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: To create a string from a char array use `new String(..)` not `.ToString()`. BTW debugging and checking the values in each step would have shown what's wrong

Comment: @AyJay debugging and stepping into the code is even easier

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did step into the code all it did was return the char array which should have returned false because they weren't the same. This was a deeper underlying issue with how the functions are implemented on the lower level

Comment: @AyJay there's no deeper underlying issue. You *didn't* check what was being compared otherwise you'd have seen it's `"System.Char[]"`

Comment: @AyJay if you did debug it, you would notice `word1Arr.ToString()` does not return what you think it returns.

Comment: Instead of comparing one `word1Arr.ToString() ` against the other, save the results into a variable first. This makes the code cleaner and easier to debug. `word1Arr.ToString()` will generate a temporary string anyway, might as well store it somewhere

Comment: @AyJay you could also add both expressions as watch variables. That would also show that something was wrong

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for actually teaching me alternative ways to debug and showing me my mistakes. I'll read more into it

Answer (score 8):

replace

```
if (word1Arr.ToString() == word2Arr.ToString())
```

with

```
if (word1Arr.SequenceEqual(word2Arr))
```

to compare the content of the arrays - because `word1Arr.ToString()` returns `"System.Char[]"` and your comparison results into

```
"System.Char[]" == "System.Char[]"
```

is always true

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this comparison:

```
if(new string(word1Arr) == new string (word2Arr))
```

`ToString` method has default implementation in `char[]` returning name of a type `System.Char[]`, that's why you are getting true when you compare two `char[]`.

Comparing to the other answer: my method created two extra instances of `string` class, while the other answer compares arrays without creating extra objects.